# Two terms of a geometric sequence are $a_4=135$ and $a_7=3645$. Write an explicit rule for the $n$-th term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Two terms of a geometric sequence are $a_4=135$ and $a_7=3645$. Write an explicit rule for the $n$-th term.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $a$ be the first term and $r$ be the common ratio, then $$a_4=ar^3 \\ a_7=ar^6$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum ar^{n-1}\\$ be the geometric series.

Then $\frac{a_7}{a_4} = \frac{3645}{135} \implies
\frac{ar^6}{ar^3} = r^3 = 27 \implies r=3$

Therefore the $n^{th}$ term is $a_n= a3^{n-1}$.

**Edit:**

Again $a= \frac{a_4}{r^3} = 5$.

Therefore $a_n=5\cdot 3^{n-1}$

Comment: We are able to solve for $a$, since we now have the value of $r$. It's solving either the equation $135 = a (3^3)$ or $3645 = a (3^6)$

Comment: You're right, I should include that too.